# Unity | Rotate the gameObject by specified angle (0~360 degree)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, angle, quaternions

I'm struggling to rotate gameObject with joystick. The joystick send the json data included value of angle to gameObject. The gameOjbect should rotate itself when receive the Jsondata. However, i'm wondering how to rotate it by angle (0 to 360 degree) in unity because all i do know is using (Vector3) position below.

```
Quaternion.LookRotation
public static Quaternion LookRotation(Vector3 forward, 
                                      Vector3 upwards = Vector3.up);
```

In conclusion, all i want to know is rotating the gameObject by the angle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`RotateAround`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html).

```
// Rotate around world y.
transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up, angle);

// Rotate around local y.
transform.RotateAround(transform.position, transform.up, angle);
```

You may found other useful stuff in [`Transform`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) documentation anyway.

Comment: Thanks!! and  sorry for late reply :-< . I've confused about the difference world position and local position. I'm wondering that using world position always show same position on mobile screen. I used the world position if i need to get touch position from the mobile screen. Is it right? Always so confused : -( ...

Comment: Local up is not always upward. If a cube is "looking" at the ground, then it's local up is simply not the same as world up (same as Unity Editor Local / Global switch on the top left). What you get from touches, and how you apply it in what view direction... ...is completely up to your implementation. I recommend to fiddle around with the GameObject transforms manually in Play Mode (this is Unity is very best at), then figure out what value / angle you want to drive. After that you can figure out how you want to drive it.

Answer (score 5):

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(90, 0, 0);
```

Rotates your gameobject to 90 degrees in x axis.

**Or you can rotate smoothly with**

```
Vector3 destination = new Vector3(90,0,0);
transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, 
                                     destination, 
                                     Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip for whoever is reading this now. `transform.RotateAround` is outdated in Unity's latest version. Need to use `transform.Rotate(Vector3 eulerAngles)` instead.

Here is an example to instantiate projectiles rotated on 'randomAngleRotation' angles.

```
Projectile newProjectile = Instantiate<Projectile> (projectile,projectileSpawn [i].position, projectileSpawn [i].rotation) as Projectile;
newProjectile.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(Random.Range(randomAngleRotation, randomAngleRotation), Random.Range(randomAngleRotation, randomAngleRotation)));
```